# bond two wifi interfaces with dhcp

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, network-bonding

I want to round-robin (mode 0) two wifi interfaces to increase overall bandwidth.  I've tried using the command line or using network manager. With the command line using the following /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  bond-master bond0

auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
  bond-master bond0

# bonding interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
   bond-mode 0
   bond-slaves none
```

And running

```
ifup wlan0
ifup wlan1
ifup bond0
```

I try and run dhclient to get a ip lease, but it never works, or if it does both interfaces do not receive data (according to speedometer). If I use network manager I'm able to create a bonded interface with two VLAN connections of my two wifi cards.  I seem to have to use nmcli in order to connect, and although it shows many interfaces connected (nmcli connect/nmcli devices), but again it doens't show that both interfaces are receiving data.

I believe my problems are one or more of

- my /etc/network/interfaces file
- my connection procedure (when do I run dhclient)
- my testing procedure (using speedometer)

Does anyone have any suggestions or woking configs they'd be willing to share? Thanks.